# connect to access database from php

Tags: php, ms-access

How to connect to access data base from php 5.3.4 without using odbc connection?

Comment: Before going down this road, you should seriously why you think Jet/ACE is a suitable back end for a web app -- it is not, in my opinion, as it was not designed for that purpose (there are threading issues and other things that make it problematic for anything other than the simplest applications).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal answer to your question, connecting to Access using something other than ODBC is to use OLEDB. See [PHP-OLEDB](http://www.phpbuilder.com/news/item.php?id=1205).

If your problem is that you're running PHP on a platform that doesn't have JET ODBC drivers (i.e., not Windows) then you should probably consider using SQLite or more Linux-friendly embedded databases.

If you're dead-set on accessing a JET database from Linux, then take a look at [mdbtools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/install/c42.htm).

Comment: I don't have choice about the db type because the company have other application using this access common db and about the machine it's a windows machine but the problem is with the X64 ODBC drivers

Comment: @Mario There are now 64-bit ODBC drivers http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en if that doesn't solve your problem try something like http://information-management-enabled.blogspot.com/2005/11/access-database-from-sql-200564.html but perhaps in reverse.